# Binding v-show to component data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I'm trying to use Vue.js to hide/show an element of my page based on a checkbox's value. Here's what I have so far:

```
<div id="myDiv" v-show="????">
<!-- stuff to be hidden -->
</div>

...

Vue.component('tab-gar-var-cb', {
        props: ['cmp_name','cmp_checked_init', 'cmp_garantie_id'],
        data: function(){
            return {
                'cmp_checked' : ''
            };
        },
        template:`  
            <span>
                <input :name="cmp_name" type="hidden" value="0">
                <input :name="cmp_name" type="checkbox" value="1" v-model="cmp_checked">
            </span>
            `,
        mounted: function(){
            this.cmp_checked = (this.cmp_checked_init == '1');
        }

    });

new Vue({
        el: "#vue-rptrenouedit-root"
    });
```

Basically, what I'd like to do is bind the 'v-show' attribute to the 'cmp-checked' data of my tab-gar-var-cb component. However, I can't figure out how to do it. Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A component's data can't be bound to anything outside its scope. From the context you've given, I can't tell where you #myDiv div is in relation to your component. The general solution would be to emit a value when `cmp_checked` changes in order for the value to be used by a parent component.

Comment: For now, the div is completely unrelated to my component. Is there a way to make it related so that I could access my component's data?

Comment: It won't be able to access the data directly unless it's within the component's template. The component will either need to emit the value which could then be passed as a prop to another component. Or you could use a [global event bus](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus), or a state manager such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) to watch for data changes between two unrelated components.